# me pueden orienar a hacer una grafica dinamica?

Tags: javascript, php, html, vue.js

soy estudiante de 6 semestre de informatica y estoy haciendo una aplicacion web
me toco hacer una tabla dinamica en donde hay un input en el que se va a ingresar un numero y con ese numero debe de crecer una barra que idica la cantidad

ya tengo echa la tabla
estoy utilizando vue,php y js
es la primera vez que uso esta pagina xd

```
<table class="col-10 table table-bordered ">
                                        <thead>
                                       
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                            <th colspan="32" class="table-secondary text-center">ACCIDENTES (#)</th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr style="text-align: center " v-for="numero1 in numerosTablas">
                                                <th scope="row" style="max-width:15px " class="bg-secondary text-white">{{numero1}}</th>
                                                <td style="max-width:15px" v-for="numero2 in 31"><label v-if="numero1 == 'DIA'">{{numero2}}</label>
                                                <input style="max-width:40px" v-else-if="numero1 == '.'"></input>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                        </table>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwKMa.png)

esa es la tabla  el input esta abajo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual es el problema???